# Use StringSplit with a Whitelist

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have strings like these:

```
animals1 = {"Cow and Milk, extracreamy and Chicken and Egg and Pig and Sheep"};
```

```
animals2 = {"Cow and Milk and Chicken and Egg and Pig and Sheep"};
```

Now I want to use `StringSplit`using " and " as expression but I was wondering if it is possible to define some kind of universal Go-List which defines  exceptions for `StringSplit` such as this one

```
whitelist = {"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg", "Cow and Milk, extracreamy"}
```

So the outcome should be

```
{"Cow and Milk, extracreamy", "Chicken and Egg", "Pig", "Sheep"}
```

and

```
{"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg", "Pig", "Sheep"}
```

respectively. More specifically, the problem is that `Cow and Milk` and `Cow and Milk, extracreamy` are defined in one Go-List....

Comment: `StringSplit[animals[[1]], 
 Prepend[Thread[whitelist -> whitelist], "and"]]` should get you started. Note the nulls in the result - this is the documented behavior of `StringSplit` for adjacent delimiters, you can just apply `DeleteCases` on the result to remove them.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for some sort of [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) algorithm.

Comment: @AntonAntonov: does this mean that there is no proper solution with a single whitelist?

Comment: @M.A. "does this mean that there is no proper solution with a single whitelist?" -- I meant two things. **1)** Your "whitelist" approach is basically NER's gazetteer approach. **2)** There is a field in Information retrieval/extraction to which your question belongs.

Comment: @AntonAntonov: Ok this suggests that there is no easy implementation in Mathematica (With easy I mean: without having advanced skills in machine learning...).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, among others:

```
  whitelist = {"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg"}  

     ReadList[StringToStream[
       "Cow and Milk and Chicken and Egg and Pig and Sheep"]
      , Word
      , RecordLists -> True
      , RecordSeparators -> whitelist
      , WordSeparators -> "and"
      , TokenWords -> whitelist]  

    Flatten[%]
    StringTrim /@ %
    DeleteCases[%, ""]
```

> {{"Cow and Milk", " ", " "}, {"Chicken and Egg", " ", " Pig ",    " Sheep"}}
>    {"Cow and Milk", " ", " ", "Chicken and Egg", " ", " Pig ", " Sheep"}
>     {"Cow and Milk", "", "", "Chicken and Egg", "", "Pig",   "Sheep"}
>    {"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg", "Pig", "Sheep"}

Another approach :

```
whitelist = {"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg"};  

StringSplit["Cow and Milk and Chicken and Egg and Pig and Sheep", # ->
     white[#] & /@ whitelist] 
If[Head[#] === white, #[[1]], StringSplit[#, "and"]] & /@ %  


Flatten[%]
StringTrim /@ % 
DeleteCases[%, ""]
```

> {white["Cow and Milk"], " and ", white["Chicken and Egg"], " and Pig and Sheep"}
>   {"Cow and Milk", {" ", " "}, "Chicken and Egg", {" ", " Pig ",    "
>   Sheep"}}
>   {"Cow and Milk", " ", " ", "Chicken and Egg", " ", " Pig ", " Sheep"}
>   {"Cow and Milk", "", "", "Chicken and Egg", "", "Pig", "Sheep"}
>   {"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg", "Pig", "Sheep"}

Answer (score 1):

A variation on ciao's suggestion in comments:

```
StringSplit["Cow and Milk and Chicken and Egg and Pig and Sheep", 
   {a : Alternatives @@ whitelist :> a, "and"}] // DeleteCases[" "] // StringTrim
```

> ```
>  {"Cow and Milk", "Chicken and Egg", "Pig", "Sheep"}
> ```

Comment: But if you add "Cow and Milk, extracreamy" to ```whitelist```and to the string respectively... put differently: is there a way that allows to distinguish between  "Cow and Milk, extracreamy" and  "Cow and Milk" when splitting the strings?